# Loop audio files using .wav format in java

Tags: java, audio, wav, javasound

i am trying to loop an audio file but when i've tried the other various methods available, my music doesn't play.

My basic code is:

```
import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;

public class PlayMusic {


    public void playSound() {
        try {
            AudioPlayer p = AudioPlayer.player;
            AudioStream as = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("02 River Flows In You.wav"));
            p.start(as);


        } catch (IOException IOE) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: basically you miss the loop code. Your code is playing only one audio file.

Comment: I see :) Thank you :)
Mmm, if i may ask... What loop code should i implement? :)

Comment: Cause i've tried a few and have failed. Any suggested codes that i can follow? :)

Comment: 1) Change `} catch (IOException IOE) {
        }` to `} catch (IOException IOE) { IOE.printStackTrace();
        }` for information on failure.  2) There is an example of looping a sound in the [Java Sound tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen sun.audio.AudioPlayer in use before! I've always used the javax.sound.sampled library.

Maybe you can tell me how you came across it. It looks to me like rather old code (10 years?) and also a bit on the limited side.

I think, if you aren't getting a single playback, you should try the URL form:

```
     AudioStream audiostream = new AudioStream(url.openStream());
     AudioPlayer.player.start(audiostream);
```

Then try putting the code in a loop? A lot depends on whether the .start command blocks or not. If it launches a separate thread (most likely), then you will have to figure out when the file ends, and I don't see any commands provided to do that! The spec also lists the possibility of creating an ContinuousAudioDataStream and managing that.

Unless there is something I don't know about this library that I should, I recommend using either a javax.sound.sampled.Clip, or javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine for playback. The Clip has a boolean you can set for looping, but requires the entire file be loaded into memory first. The SourceDataLine plays back from a url or file location, and can implement a listener to tell you when the file is done.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/playing.html